How do I use a grease pencil layer to make only certain parts of objects behind it invisible?
I am using a grease pencil holdout material to cut out footage of a car driving with a character drawn on top. I want to make the red layer cut out the video behind it so the car looks like it's driving on the moon.
Both videos, the car and the moon, are images as planes. What is the easiest way to do this? I am using Blender 4.1 running Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon.


